# SQL Server 2008 R2 hangs when adding perfmon counters

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, perfmon

System is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 64 bit
Running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2425.0 (X64)

This is a newly built and deployed server, operating in an active/passive cluster. Dual Xeon procs, 64gb RAM, C drive is local Raid 1, all other volumes are DAS.

Often when I run perfmon, and click on the green plus icon to add counters, perfmon hangs for 3-4 seconds, and SQL Server hangs completely for about 60 seconds.

This is somewhat intermittent, but has happened 5 times in 2 days. perhaps half of the times I've run perfmon. I'm naturally hesitant to cause this issue purposefully as this is our production system.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This issue was caused by running the Community Technology Preview version of SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by running the Community Technology Preview version of SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1.